# How to render a variable from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web3js

So I'm trying to render a constructor variable but when I add the lines that renders it, the whole page goes blank. I don't know if it's that `this.balance()` is not called there or sm.
I'm new so help is appreciated :)

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      balance: ""
    }
  }

  balance = async() => {
    const web3 = window.web3
    const balance = web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account)
    this.setState({balance})
  }

render(){
    this.balance()
    return(
      <section id="payments">
        Payments
        <Nav/>
        <p>balance: {this.state.balance}</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
```

Comment: you can call this.balance() inside componentDidMount() instead of render method

Comment: You're not waiting for `web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account)` which looks asynchronous

Comment: In addition to the componentDidMount comment, the general "don't update state during render" applies for subsequent updates. If that balance needs to be updated based on something throughout the lifetime of the component, have _that something_ trigger the balance update. (and that can be user actions, a timer, etc. etc.)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you very much, but where do I call "that something"?

Comment: Depends on the "something"? If it's a timer, you'd start it when the component mounts (and stop it when it unmounts), if it's based on some user action, you're going to have to write an event listener tied to the event you care about (e.g. page focus/blur, a refresh button click, etc).